# Android, get text from url works fine in eclipse but not on device

Tags: java, android

As title suggests this code works fine in eclipse, but as soon as I export and try to use it only on the device it doesn't bring anything down and simply returns null.

It is supposed to read text from a url and display it in a text view

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, its probably something fairly simple but I just cant see it

```
public class nextEvent extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

String Event;
TextView eventText;
TextView titleText;

String HTML;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newevent);

    titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Title);
    eventText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Event);



            try { 
            getHTML();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
            eventText.setText("" + HTML);
    }


private void getHTML() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException 

{
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://masterzangetsu.eu/Apps/rocksoctest"); //URL!
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
    String result = "";

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        result += line + "\n";
        HTML = result;
    }

}


public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
```

and heres the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroller"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Upcoming Events"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Event"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="Sever Event Update Failed" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

any help would be great

Comment: works fine in eclipse? You mean emulator?

Comment: Do not forget to add INTERNET permission. Also, you would better to put network operations in background thread, because on API > HONEYCOMB you will get NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Move your code to background thread or AsyncTask because you cannot perfrom networking on UI Thread since Android 3.0

Comment: Any exception? Logcat output is must if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your emulator is probably running an older version of Android than your device and you're executing a networking call on the UI thread inside of a try-catch block that is hiding your error ;)  The older emulator will work fine.  Your device will not allow that.  Use an AsyncTask{} to make your network call.

To illustrate this point get rid of your e.printStackTrace() and put a Log.e() in there that dumps to the LogCat.

Comment: AsyncTask is a class, not function.

Answer (score 1):

You are performing an `Http` call on the `UI Thread`. Probably you set up your emulator with an older version of `Android` `(pre 3.0)` than your device (`probably post 3.0`). You should use `Thread` or `AsyncTask` to perform every potential blocking call

Comment: -1 seriously?  Answer with exactly the same thing I did.  Weak.

Comment: @BillMote I am sorry. I have not voted down you answer. Actially I can not see you answer too